# Sqlite truncating data that has embedded commas

Tags: sqlite, truncation

I have data in a sqlite table that has embedded commmas.  The data from the first comma to the end of the column value is being truncated. Is there a setting to tell sqlite which delimiter to use internally - to avoid this issue?

To illustrate: in the following insert operation

```
insert into my_table (batch, statename, envcd) 
values (10100000,'CCB-W#2013-10-08,CCB-B#2013-10-08,CCB-A#2013-10-08','hostname');
```

The statename ends up being truncated to just CCB-W#2013-10-08

```
select statename from my_table where batch=10100000 and envcd='hostname';

CCB-W#2013-10-08
```

Comment: These exact statements work for me.

Comment: @CL  So you see a comma separated list of three items returned?

Comment: Yes. In an empty database, I executed `create table my_table(batch, statename, envcd);` and those two statements, and got the original back.

Comment: @CL huh.. well i have confirmed this behavior dozens of times on my mac.. will try on another platform in a bit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a repeatable issue on sqlite.  I moved to H2 (successor of hsqldb) and the problems went away.